# The Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor(MSVSMON.EXE) doesn't appear to be running on the remote computer

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I don't have any kind of remote debuggers on my system. I don't know why all of a sudden I am getting this error:

> The Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor(MSVSMON.EXE) doesn't appear to be running on the remote computer

What could be wrong with Visual Studio 2012? I notice the Local Windows Debugger is not selectable either:

[image: Screenshot]

I can build projects, but can't run them from inside of Visual Studio. I'm on Windows 7 sp1 x64 and Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.

Comment: Make sure it says "Local Windows Debugger" next to the green arrow on the toolbar.

Comment: Its not selectable! at all! see http://i42.tinypic.com/9ien83.jpg

Comment: something to note, i used to work on this project in Visual Studio 2013 before i uninstall my former windows and install a new one.Could that be the cause? if so how can i solve it?

Comment: It is the kind of warning you can get when you allow the jitter to generate a 64-bit program.  Since VS is a 32-bit program, it must use the remote debugger to debug the program.  Anti-malware is the usual culprit for that not working out well, the aggressive stuff is not graceful when it sees an EXE file appearing from nowhere and using a named pipe next, so disable it first to see if that puts you ahead.  A programmer's machine is invariably better off with the solution included with the OS.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks alot, its been 4 years since I had that issue. I dont recall how I fixed it, and sure enough, if I encounter similar issue, I'll use your advice on that ;)